# Using montex along with babel

Tags: babel

I'm trying to typeset a document that'd use a lot of languages and scripts.
Currently it starts like this:

```
\documentclass[fontset=ubuntu,UTF8,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}            % utf8 encoding
\usepackage[mongolian,english,russian]{babel}  % russian, mongolian 
\usepackage{indentfirst}
%\usepackage{misccorr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}  %fine font size control
\usepackage{CJKutf8} %chinese 
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex} %pinyin transliteration for Mo Li Hua
\usepackage[bicig]{mls} %mongolian uighur bicig

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \LARGE BLUES\\
\end{center}

%russian text here

\reflectbox{МОЗГ}\\
Мууу!                           мууу!\\
Давайте вместе кушать мозг, когда он из коровы,\\

%more russian text here

%english text here

%and now chinese
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}
好一朵美麗的茉莉花\\
好一朵美麗的茉莉花\\
芬芳美麗滿枝椏\\
又香又白人人誇\\
讓我來將你摘下\\
送給別人家\\
茉莉花呀茉莉花\\
\end{CJK}

%actual chinese over, pinyin transliteration here
\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
h\v{a}o y\={i} du\v{o} m\v{e}il\`{i} de m\`{o}lihu\={a}\\
h\v{a}o y\={i} du\v{o} m\v{e}il\`{i} de m\`{o}lihu\={a}\\
f\={e}nf\={a}ng m\v{e}il\`{i} m\v{a}n zh\={i}y\={a}\\
y\`{o}u xi\={a}ng y\`{o}u b\'{a}i r\'{e}nr\'{e}n ku\={a}\\
r\`{a}ng w\v{o} l\'{a}i ji\={a}ng n\`{i} zh\={a}ixi\`{a}\\
s\`{o}ng g\v{e}i bi\'{e}r\'{e}nji\={a}\\
m\`{o}lihu\={a} ya m\`{o}lihu\={a}\\
\end{otherlanguage}

%other stuff follows, which at some point includes a mongolian excerpt

\end{document}
```

I try building it, but I get a lot of errors like

```
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/montex/english.def)
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/montex/russian.def
 ! LaTeX Error: Command \Asbuk already defined. Or name \end...
 illegal, see p.192 of the manual. See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX
 Companion for explanation. Type H <return> for immediate help.
```

As I understand it, the problem is that I'm using some commands from some package and then try using another package that redefines some of those commands.
What do I do?

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 x64 and texlive 2016.

Comment: it depends what you want to do, after loading the first package you could use `\let\Asbuk\relax` then the version in the second package would be available. If you just want the first, do the same but swap the package loading order, if you need both, you need to rename one of them (which is possible but a bit trickier)

Comment: From the documentation of `mls`: “At present, MonTeX is *not* built with `babel` compatibility in mind. It must be seen as a stand-alone extension similar to `german.sty` or the `CJK` package.” (emphasis as in the original).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks, I'll look into that. egreg, thanks for pointing that out, but I wondered if there's a clever way to avoid running into that non-compatibility.